# Alter a datetime in Oracle and set time to 9 am

Tags: oracle, datetime, stored-procedures

i have `28-APR-2016 10:05:07` date as parameter in stored procedure. This may be the current time also as string date.

i need to set the time to `9 am` to check the shift start timing.

```
 SELECT TO_DATE('28-APR-2016 10:05:07', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual;
```

I am new to oracle. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the date with 9:00 a.m., then you can do:

```
SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE('28-APR-2016 10:05:07', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) + 9/24.0
FROM dual;
```

You can also use:

```
SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE('28-APR-2016 10:05:07', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) + INTERVAL '9' HOUR
FROM dual;
```

I'm just old-fashioned so I tend to use the first method.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, but this query will give me date in string format. I need to use it for further comparison with a table column

Comment: @MayankPathak . . . No, this will give you the value as a `date` column.

Comment: @MayankPathak - to get it as a character string you'd have to do `SELECT TO_DATE(TRUNC(TO_DATE('28-APR-2016 10:05:07', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) + INTERVAL '9' HOUR, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM dual;`

Comment: @BobJarvis . . . Utterly unnecessary.  The value is already a `date`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I realize that. I was trying to demonstrate to OP that in order for your query to have returned a string there'd have to be Yet Another Function Call in there.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - AGGGGGHHHHHH!!!!! That's what I meant! :-)  Must....sleep...before........coding..........(whump!)!!!!! :-)